# Cannot install handlebars on Node from command line

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, command-line, handlebars.js

I've been trying to get handlebars to work with node using. My book has instructed me to install handlebars like this: `npm install --save express3-handlebar`. That threw an error

`npm WARN deprecated express3-handlebars @0.5.2: THIS PACKAGE HAS BEEN RENAMED TO: express-handlebars`

so I tried `npm install --save express-handlebar`.

When I tried to start the server `node meadowlark.js`, the command prompt displayed `Express started on....`

But when I put localhost into the browser I received the following:

```
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
   at new View (C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\project\meadowlark\site\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:48:42)
   at EventEmitter.app.render (C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\project\meadowlark\site\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:509:12)
   at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\project\meadowlark\site\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:904:7)
   at require.create.defaultLayout (C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\project\meadowlark\site\meadowlark.js:20:6)
   at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\project\meadowlark\site\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:58:5)
   at trim_prefix (C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\project\meadowlark\site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:269:13)
   at C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\project\meadowlark\site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:238:9
   at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\project\meadowlark\site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:313:12)
   at C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\project\meadowlark\site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:229:12
   at Function.match_layer (C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\project\meadowlark\site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:296:3)
```

Then I noticed in my index file I still had

```
var app = express();
// set up handlebars view engine
var handlebars = require('express3-handlebars')
    .create({ defaultLayout:'main' });
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

So I changed that to remove the `3` from the third line. Still the same long lines of errors. What have I done wrong to receive this error? Am I not in the correct directory when I do the handlebars install? I have tried it from my app root directory, and the file within it that contains my `index.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.render('home');
});
app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
 res.render('about');
});
// 404 catch-all handler (middleware)
app.use(function(req, res, next){
 res.status(404);
 res.render('404');
});
// 500 error handler (middleware)
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
 console.error(err.stack);
 res.status(500);
 res.render('500');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express started on http://localhost:' +
        app.get('port') + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
});

var app = express();
// set up handlebars view engine
var handlebars = require('express3-handlebars')
    .create({ defaultLayout:'main' });
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

The example I'm working with is from *[Web Development with Node & Express](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032977.do)* (Ethan Brown).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main issue I see with your code is that you are creating two instances of `app`:

```
var app = express(); // I see this line twice in your code
```

This means you are configuring your handlebars on the wrong instance of your app, hence `"No default engine was specified"`.

If you remove the second instantiation you should be golden.  Here is an example of how I would rewrite that code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars')
  .create({ defaultLayout:'main' });
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.set('port', 3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('home');
});
app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
  res.render('about');
});
// 404 catch-all handler (middleware)
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.status(404);
  res.render('404');
});
// 500 error handler (middleware)
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500);
  res.render('500');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express started on http://localhost:' +
  app.get('port') + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
});
```

You can try that with and without the `3` in your require statement, but it should work either way.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for the delay accepting!